perl regex negative lookahead replacement with wildcard
Updated with real and more complicated task:
The problem is to substitute a certain pattern to different result with or without _ndm.
The input is a text file with certain line like:
/<random path>/PAT1/<txt w/o _ndm>
/<random path>/PAT1/<txt w/ _ndm>

I need change those to
/<ramdom path>/PAT1/<sub1>
/<random path>/PAT1/<sub2>_ndm

I wrote a perl command to process it:
perl -i -pe 's#PAT1/.*_ndm#<sub2>_ndm#; s#PAT1/.*(?!_ndm)#<sub1>#' <input_file>

However, it doesn't work as expected. the  are all substituted to  instead of _ndm.

Original post:
I need use shell command to replace any string not ending with _ndm to another string (this is an example):
abc
def
def_ndm

to
ace
ace
def_ndm

I tried with perl command
perl -pe 's/.*(?!_ndm)/ace/'

However I found wildcard didn't work with negative lookahead as my expected. Only if I include wildcard in negative pattern, it can skip def_ndm correctly; but because negative lookahead is a zero length one, it can't replace normal string any more.
any idea?

Why use negative lookahead in the first place? Why not simply print the original string on match and otherwise print a different one, e.g. perl -ne  'print /_ndm$/ ? $_ : "ace\n"'

@SteffenUllrich This is the simplified description of the issue. The original task is to do a more complicated replacement in a text. To change //PAT1/<\w>/ to /<some random unchanged/PAT1// but keep //PAT1/<\w>_ndm/ unchanged.

It might be useful to present the more complicated problem then, since maybe negative lookahead isn't the best approach to tackle this more complicated problem either. See also XY problem

I think you want perl -pe 's#PAT1/\K.*(?=_ndm)#<sub2>#; s#PAT1/\K.*$(?<!_ndm)#<sub1>#'

So when you write <txt w/o _ndm> you don't mean you have that text there, you mean that we should imagine "text without _ndm at the end". That is slightly confusing, and it would actually be better with a sample. With a sample we can also cut and paste the input and all have the same reference.

Quick fix is to add \K to keep the part before, and then change the middle ; to ||, so that the second substitution is only run if the first one fails. Not sure how stable it is, but seems to work on the limited sample.

Daisy chained matches
Force PAT1 to be the parent directory and then see whether the final name ends in _ndm. Note the need to squirrel away values of match variables $1 and $2 into $a and $b because the second match (against /_ndm$/) wipes out the previous capture variables.
while (<>) {
  chomp;
  if (s#(/PAT1/)([^/]+)$#($a,$b) = ($1, $2); $a . ($b =~ /_ndm$/ ? "sub2_ndm" : "sub1")#e) {
    print $_, "\n";
  }
  else {
    print "No match: $_\n";
  }
}

Try it online.
Check which alternative matched
Find PAT1 as above and then give two alternatives for how the match can succeed. Note the use of named patterns to avoid having to count left-parentheses and a fixed-width negative look-behind for the _ndm case. Strictly speaking, only one of the look-behind assertions is necessary, but you may prefer keeping both to emphasize what’s happening.
while (<>) {
  chomp;
  if (s{(?<prefix>/PAT1/) (?: (?<ndm>[^/]+)(?<=_ndm) | (?<nondm>[^/])+(?<!_ndm) )$}
       {$+{prefix} . (exists $+{nondm} ? "sub1" : "sub2_ndm")}ex)
  {
    print $_, "\n";
  }
  else {
    print "No match: $_\n";
  }
}

Try it online.
Output
Given input of
/foo/bar/PAT1/veeblefetzer
/baz/PAT1/quux_ndm
/nope/nope
/also/nope/PAT1/dir/dir/dir_ndm

both output
/foo/bar/PAT1/sub1
/baz/PAT1/sub2_ndm
No match: /nope/nope
No match: /also/nope/PAT1/dir/dir/dir_ndm


As you've discovered, "PAT1/txt_ndm" =~ m#PAT1/.*(?!_ndm)# matches. Specifically, it matches PAT1/txt_ndm. Note that PAT1/txt_ndm isn't followed by _ndm.
To only match the text up to _ndm (PAT1/txt), you can use the following:
PAT1/(?:(?!_ndm).)*

